# Not able to use attributes in Custom-tags jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl, custom-tag

I am developing a custom-tag handler in jsp which accepts one attribute named "yourname".
The .tld file and tag handler files contain the same attribute name(I've checked the case as well). But somehow while I run the web-app, i get an exception. The exception message says "Attribute yourname invalid for tag sayhello according to TLD".

This is the tag information in tld file.

```
<tag>
<name>sayhello</name>
<tag-class>check.PrintTagHandler</tag-class>
<body-content>scriptless</body-content>
<attribute>yourname</attribute>
</tag>
```

This is the property name in the bean.

```
private String yourname;
```

This is the call

```
<hello:sayhello yourname="ABC"/>
```

Tag Declaration:

```
<%@taglib prefix="hello" uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/newtag_library2"%>
```

Everything seems to be correct but I am getting the exception.

Plese help.

Comment: is getter setter for yourname attribute in place?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar: Yes they are in place. When i don't use attribute, it is working fine. It is printing Welcome null. The problem is when I use the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone..

The tld should have been like this.

```
<attribute>
<name>yourname</name>    
<required>true</required>
<rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>    
</attribute>
```

instead of

```
<attribute>yourname</attribute>
```